# QDoubleSpinBox prefix position

Tags: user-interface, qt4, qspinbox

I'm making a financial program with qt.
I just added a QDoubleSpinBox to my dialog, in this spin box the user must insert the price of some products, so I set the prefix to my currency symbol.
Now I wanted to ask if there's a way to put the prefix to left and the numbers to right.

Answer (score 1):

The `prefix` is prepended to the start of the displayed value, `suffix` is appended to the end of the displayed value.

[image]

As you can see the `prefix` is indeed at the left of the numbers. Anyways why would you need to change the `prefix` position? If you need to append a string to the end of the value just change the `suffix`, not the `prefix`.

Or perhaps I didn't understand the question correctly. If what you need is to align the prefix to the left and the numbers to the right like this:

[image]

You can visually adjust it by adding tab characters at the end of the `prefix`.

e.g. `doubleSpinBox->setPrefix(tr("[prefix]\t"));`

Comment: This lacks the flexibility required for decent alignment. You have to 1)calculate how many tabs are required for each component and 2)recalculate every time 1) if you UI is resizable. This solution is similar to aligning text in a text editor (Word, LibreOffice etc.) with manually adjusting the position of each word/line using tabulation and spacebar...